# Why did the compiler output differently when compiling two similar classes?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, g++, compiler-warnings

Here is an exercise from *C++ Primer 5th Edition*:

> Exercise 14.26: Define subscript operators for your **StrVec**, **String**,
>   StrBlob, and StrBlobPtr classes.(P.566)

The class `StrVec` compiled without any error nor warning.Below is the class body:

```
/**
 * @brief   The StrVec class  a std::vector like class without template
 *          std:string is the only type it holds.
 */
class StrVec
{
public:
    //! default constructor
    StrVec():
        element(nullptr), first_free(nullptr), cap(nullptr){}

    // etc      

    //! public members
          std::string& operator [](std::size_t n)       {return element[n];}
    const std::string& operator [](std::size_t n) const {return element[n];}  
    //                                            ^^^^^
    // etc    
private:    
    //! data members
    std::string* element;       //  pointer to the first element
    std::string* first_free;    //  pointer to the first free element
    std::string* cap;           //  pointer to one past the end

    std::allocator<std::string> alloc;
    // etc
};
```

When compiling the class `String`, a warning was generated, as shown below:

```
/**
 * @brief std::string like class without template
 *
 *        design:
 *
 *        [0][1][2][3][unconstructed chars][unallocated memory]
 *        ^           ^                    ^
 *        elements    first_free           cap
 */
class String
{
public:
    //! default constructor
    String();

    // etc

          char operator [](std::size_t n)       {return elements[n];}
    const char operator [](std::size_t n) const {return elements[n];}
    //                                    ^^^^^
private:    
    //! data members
    char* elements;
    char* first_free;
    char* cap;

    std::allocator<char> alloc;    
    // etc
};
```

Warning from the compiler:

```
warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
     const char operator [](std::size_t n) const {return elements[n];}
                                           ^
```

The compiler I was using:

```
gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~13.04)
```

Why is it so? Is there any significant difference between the two classes?

Comment: In the second class you are referencing a direct data type (`char`) instead of a data reference (`std::string&`), i.e., a pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const char operator [](std::size_t n) const {return elements[n];}`
This returns a const copy of `elements[n]`, which is no use at all. You return a const when you don't want the caller changing your stuff, but since you're returning a copy here, you wouldn't be changing anything anyways.

Your first example is returning a const reference, which is what you should do here.

Comment: Why would you ever return a `const char&` rather than just a `char` ? To turn it into a `const char *` perhaps ? I can see that, but its a little... odd.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I would do so out of habit; if I always return `const {DATATYPE}&` then I never need to worry about the difference...

Comment: I guess just to be uniform with other `operator[]`? But yeah, not any real benefit with `char`.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit yeah, the only benefit I can muster is later using said-reference to address (`const`, of course) the element via a pointer, which would work with `const char&`, but not `char` rvalue.

Comment: @WhozCraig Cus, as I just found from all the answers, I did a stupid mistake..I should have uesed char&

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit No truer words have ever been written. I make them *daily* (or so it seems sometimes).

Answer (score 5):

The first version is returning a reference to an array element.  Whether or not this is a const reference determines whether you can just read the element's value or write to the element also.

The second version is returning a copy of an array element.  If this is deliberate, you only need

```
char operator [](std::size_t n) const {return elements[n];}
```

If you wanted two overloads of `operator []`, one that allows an element to be read and another that allows it to be written, you need to return references instead

```
      char& operator [](std::size_t n)       {return elements[n];}
const char& operator [](std::size_t n) const {return elements[n];}
```